# How do I make it so the items are unique and don't duplicate?

Tags: c#

How do I make it so that the 500 doesn't duplicate here, letting the 900 appear by itself? If I can fix it here, then I can do it with the other 15 entries.

```
string[] prices =
        {
            "₱500.00", "₱9,000.00", "₱4,000.00", "₱550.00", "₱350.00", "₱1,200.00", "₱3,500.00",
            "₱5,000.00", "₱10,000.00", "₱600.00", "₱1,000.00", "₱800.00", "₱2,500.00", "₱3,000.00"
        };
        foreach (string selling in toSell.Items)
        {
            if (!itemTag.Items.Contains(prices))
                {
                if (selling == "Electric Fan")
                    itemTag.Items.Add("₱500.00");
                else if (selling == "Refrigerator")
                    itemTag.Items.Add("₱9,000.00");
            }
        }
```

[How the program looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSpol.png)

Comment: I would suggest creating some type of Money object with two fields, one denoting the currency and one denoting the amount. You then override Equals to check that both those two fields match. Store it in a set which will then take care of the deduping. Also, you may want to have some type of functional method to map these prices to a currency object so they can handle the commas, symbols and periods.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the items don't duplicate, but the prices do. So, there are two solutions to this:

Either:

Allow an item to be selected only once (since you can control the quantity from the counter right there). This can be done by declaring an integer array of the same size as the number of elements, linking each item to a particular element and changing the value of an element, just like a switch.

```
string[] prices =
    {
        "₱500.00", "₱9,000.00", "₱4,000.00", "₱550.00", "₱350.00", "₱1,200.00", "₱3,500.00",
        "₱5,000.00", "₱10,000.00", "₱600.00", "₱1,000.00", "₱800.00", "₱2,500.00", "₱3,000.00"
    };
int[] checkers[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    foreach (string selling in toSell.Items)
    {
        if (!itemTag.Items.Contains(prices))
            {
            if (selling == "Electric Fan" && checkers[0]==0){
                itemTag.Items.Add(prices[0]);
                checkers[0]=1;
            }
            else if (selling == "Refrigerator" && checkers[1]==0){
                itemTag.Items.Add(prices[1]);
                checkers[1]=1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Or, you can just eliminate the quantity counter completely, and add every item multiple times in the list (I won't recommend this one.)

Also, I noticed that you created a string array for prices, but aren't using it.

Comment: When I double click the appliance in the far left list box, the two list boxes in the right should display their according strings. Electric fan should be paired with 500 only, and the refrigerator should be paired with 9000 only.

Comment: I tried using the code you made, and the price is somehow stuck at 500 now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashSet collection that will ensure all your items are unique